# How to get the built in news.reads action to publish to Facebook?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Per the documentation located here:

`https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/news/`

I should be able to post a news.reads?article action by posting the following:

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/news.reads?article=[article url]`

To test this, I use the Graph API Explorer, found at:

`http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer`

When I attempt this with my app selected, and me/news.reads?article=http://thesumm.it/CS/21006.html, it tells me "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: news.reads".

When I try this with the default Graph API Explorer, it tells me "(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions."  I think this latter one is likely that it won't grant me the extended permissions for the Graph API Explorer.

Is it possible for me to publish actions with news.reads?article at this point?  If so, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the programme is in Beta, its not currently possible to publish news.reads actions.

In the meantime, create your own read action and post to that instead:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/appnamespace:read?article=ARTICLE_URL&access_token=TOKEN&method=post
```

Comment: I'm having this same issue just now - I noticed the question was posted in October... Is this feature still in beta or should it now be publicly available?

Comment: publishing to /me/news.reads is a private api and is still not generally available.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Any idea when it is due to become public?