# Is the news.reads action on the Open Graph available yet?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

I'm having the same issue as described in this post:

[How to get the built in news.reads action to publish to Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667088/how-to-get-the-built-in-news-reads-action-to-publish-to-facebook)

I noticed this question was posted way back in October. Is this feature *still* in beta or is it available now?

If it's still in Beta, any idea when it will be released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was released on January 18th, 2012

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/634/